# Is this a too broad because it's a tool request?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

[Here's the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29308174/603977) [Here's the question before the edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29308174/2)

- The edit invalidated two answers and was done "to protect it from being removed"
- The question also mentions other tools that the OP tried to install
- It's *incredibly* hard to find a guide on installing any command-line profiler.
- The question asks for instructions to install, not a tool itself
- Tools other than `gprof` are *very* hard to install
- The googlers will suffer hours of lost time
- @Kyll, the editor, did not have to get his/her edit approved

**Is this *really* a software recommendation?**

Comment: `Is this really a software reccomendation?` Post edit, no, clearly not.  Pre edit, yes, unambiguously so.

Comment: @Servy if Kyll had to get his/her edit approved, it wouldn't have passed

Comment: Users with 2k reputation can edit any post without having to go through review.  This is very much by design because the system trusts them to make good edits.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I know that.

Comment: @Servy but why pre edit?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Potentially, yes.  The question would of course merit closure without such an edit though; with the edit it looks like it's an appropriate question; at least it would no longer merit deletion as a software recommendation question.

Comment: `what other command line tools can be used` is definitely a tool/resource request.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Because it said, "what other command line tools can be used to get the similar reports from `gprof`?"  That's asking for a tool recommendation, pretty unambiguously.  What makes you think that it isn't?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I proposed the edit to read `how can I install another commandline tool`, but it was rejected/not yet approved

Comment: What if it was migrated to softwarerecs.se?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Such a question would be unanswerable, so I would certainly hope it would be rejected.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC The question is too old to be migrated.  Not being an active member of SR.SE, I couldn't comment on whether the question would be on topic there.

Comment: @Servy Shog9 edited to ask for a tool, but in a way that's not a tool request.

Comment: No Shog didn't ask for a tool there.  Like the revision comment says, the edit focuses on how to solve the problem.  If the solution is achievable through a tool, then so be it.  But the edit does not ask for tools.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC And yet it's still *really* broad.  Probably too broad, by the looks of it, although I'm not an expert in the area.

Comment: @Servy The dude works for stackoverflow.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I'm well aware of that.  That doesn't make the question sufficiently narrow, especially given that Shog didn't even say that the question isn't too broad.

Answer (score 12):

It's a request for a recommendation if you request a recommendation. Yes, it's really that simple - if someone can post a legitimate answer to your question that consists of nothing more than, "use software named X", it's a recommendation question.

Fortunately, any worthwhile recommendation question can be turned into a perfectly good question that *doesn't* ask for recommendations, and probably even attract better answers as a result. All you have to do is **ask how to solve the problem you're facing** instead of where to find a bit of software that solves it.

#### Examples:

- "What full-featured PDF libraries exist for Java?" -> "How can I create a PDF with embedded vector images in Java?"
- "What SMS services are best for spamming people?" -> "How can I send unlimited SMS messages to thousands of people?"
- "What command line profiling tools exist for OS X?" -> "How can I automate profiling on OS X?"

...you get the idea. Focus on the problem, and if there's a pre-made software solution you'll still get it. Focus on a (potentially mythical) pre-made software solution, you'll get spam, unhelpful links, and *maybe* an actual solution.

Comment: Of course, when performing this transformation you should ensure that the end result isn't an overly broad question, as that's often the case, including, by the looks of it, this specific case.

Comment: I'll leave that to folks who use OSX to figure out. So far, it would appear to have between 0 and 1 legit answers, so I'm not really worried.